# Access call log in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can I access the call log of iPhone through application. Is this feature added in iPhone OS 4.0??? As what ever I searched for OS below 4.0 and it is not there.

Thanks in advance,
VIshaL

Comment: you've asked 14 questions and not accepted any answers, perhaps you should?

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in the 3.0 and earlier SDKs. The 4.0 SDK is currently covered by an NDA so I can't comment on that directly. If you sign up for the iOS developer program you can look at the documentation yourself.